# Can I see specifically what React's diffing algorithm is detecting has changed?

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to gain visibility on the React shadow DOM diffing algorithm to debug a problem I'm having. Specifically, I'd like to see exactly what React will be changing on the next render. Only the className? The entire element?

tl;dr if you're curious, I have a css transition triggered by a class change which doesn't work, so I'm trying to figure out whether it's because React is seeing more changes than just the class and replacing the entire element (which I believe would prevent any style transitions from working).

Comment: If you use the react dev-tools it should highlight what updates in the dom when an update happens. Maybe you can try adding a unique `key` to your element so react knows it is the same from the previous render.

Comment: I do have a unique key, and looking in the react dev-tools really doesn't cut it, some elements just instantly collapse and I can't see what actually happened.

Comment: If items are collapsing like that when it re-renders, it might mean a parent component is unmounting and then mounting again. Try adding a console.log to `componentDidMount` and see if its getting called

Comment: Yes, you're right, it is unmounting and re-mounting! I have no idea WHY it's unmounting though...

Comment: The problem component might need to be key'd for some reason :x Then your issue might be resolved! :D

Comment: No I tried that, not working :( In fact I tried keying every single component up the hierarchy chain with globally unique keys, to no avail :p

Comment: I do feel closer to an answer now though, thanks a lot

Comment: Find the parent component that is re-mounting, as that component will cause all it's childrent to re-mount. If you can prevent that one from re-mounting somehow then it should fix it. Maybe you should post the code to that component for us to look at

Comment: Yes that could be my next step, it's just big messy code and I don't expect others to go through it all in this state...

Comment: Actually I should mention you should look at the component that's remounting's parent. It could be returning `null`, for example, instead of `<Component />`. Or something similar. :)

Comment: yep, that doesn't seem to be the case :( This is the repo: https://github.com/shawninder/music Problem occurs when clicking the toggle of a search result, but to get things to work you'll need 2 other repos (described in the README), which is why I don't expect people to dive in the code until I get a minimal reproduction set up...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174837/discussion-between-shawn-and-brett-merrifield).

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the problematic components are made draggable with https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd